# "Getting requirements to build wheel ... error" when trying install --editable

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I am running:

```
pip install --editable .
```

and get the following:

```
Obtaining file:///content/nlp_tokenization_project
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpkhbslig1 Check the logs for full command output.
```

I made sure I have the Wheel package:

```
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.35.1)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you try ```pip install -e```

Comment: Please show the complete error log.

Comment: I'll be happy to, how can I do that? I'm using google colab.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I tried to install a local package into my project's virtual environment:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
.venv/bin/python .venv/share/python-wheels/pep517-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp25qfke7j
```

The solution was to simply remove the offending pep517 wheel:

```
rm .venv/share/python-wheels/pep517-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

After running `pip install -e .` again, the build requirements were obtained automatically and everything worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to use.

```
pip3 install --editable
```